# Basic Drilling/Production/Reservoir Engineering Terms

Tags: mechanical-engineering, petroleum-engineering, drilling

I am trained as a seismic geophysicist but really enjoy getting to translate what I know into what other people can understand and use for their applications, if necessary.

For those with working in and/or retain practical knowledge of Oil/Gas E&P in terms of the engineering side, what is a usable or comprehensive list of terms to know in order to *read* (and understand) data from my engineer colleagues? For example, I know terms such as Water Cut, GOR, etc. I want to learn more and expand this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of online reference. I entered "dictionary oil terms" into a search engine & came up with these as an example:

[The Schlumberger Oilfield Glossary](https://www.glossary.oilfield.slb.com/)

[Glossary of Oil and Gas Terms -](https://cogcc.state.co.us/COGIS_Help/glossary.htm)

[Bruin Glossary of Oil and Natural Gas Terms](http://bruinep.com/glossary-of-oil-and-natural-gas-terms/)

[Oil and Gas Glossary of Terms for Production Financing](https://bfs-usa.com/oil-gas-glossary-of-terms/)

[OPIS Glossary of Terms](https://www.opisnet.com/resources/glossary-of-terms/)

[Oil & Gas Dictionary of Historical Terminology](http://www.oil150.com/about-oil/oil-gas-dictionary/)

There are many more references.